# Lock Input as Needed on Form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a input form element which I will like to be able to lock & prevent input once it has returned a value manually by clicking some image, checkbox, etc. It returns results on keyup via ajax.

Question is how would you approach this:

An function via Jquery to disable this input when users what to lock results?

An Ajax call which disables this input field when users what to lock results?

Any other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple jQuery calls would suffice, I think.

```
// To disable 
$('#someElement').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

// To enable 
$('#someElement').removeAttr('disabled');
```